# Where can I find info about this device?

Tags: identification

This is a PCB from an IR cooker. I am looking for info about the three-terminal device in the top left of the picture (with the label BT16A below it).

[image]

I found [these devices (mostly triacs)](https://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=BT16A) but none of these seems to match. I also found [these triacs with no. BTA16](https://www.alldatasheet.com/view.jsp?Searchword=Bta16%20datasheet&gclid=CjwKCAjwgZCoBhBnEiwAz35RwuMHjjQT9f71xpes6vdQ1jevZOzMHdh5boK1ndZFtT7cCA21fF0yrhoCAQgQAvD_BwE).

However, this doesn't seem to be a triac, because the voltage drop across it changes when I change the cooker's temperature. To me, it seems like a transistor that is controlled by a PWM signal. It also has a heat sink on top of it (which is removed in the picture).

**Edit:** the lower terminal is probably the gate, because the voltage drop occurs across the other two terminals.

Comment: Fold it over and check the marking on front side.

Comment: Or if you're concerned about breaking the leads when folding it over, desolder it.

Comment: I did fold it but there is no label on it.

Comment: IR cooker or induction cooker?

Comment: IR (infra-red) cooker

Comment: If it's similar to a transistor, perhaps it's a mosfet? Could be used to control the power